# CSS box-shadow overflowing elements

Tags: javascript, css

I have a simple jsfiddle example in here http://jsfiddle.net/RQ4F2/1/

The blu `box-shadow` is actually overflowing, covering a little part of the elements , is it possible to make it not ?

So that elements shows a full white background inside of themselfs?

Comment: Margins like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/RQ4F2/2/) acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting `box-shadow` for the spans, you should set `box-shadow` for some pseudo-element of the span (such as the `:before`). That way you can put the `box-shadow` to the back by using `z-index`, the spans will be on top and cover the `box-shadow`:

```
span {
  width:100px;
  padding:20px;
  float:left;
  border-radius:100%;
  height:100px;
  background:white;    
  position:relative;    
}
span:before {
  content:'';
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border-radius:50%;
  left:0; top:0;
  background:white;  
  box-shadow:0px 0px 20px 4px blue;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RQ4F2/5/).

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that adding a margin isn't what you're after and you'd like to have the circles touching but without the fade overlapping.

To do this you could have another inner span, positioned absolute with the box shadow overridden:

```
 <span><span class="in">&nbsp;</span></span>

 span.in{
         position:absolute;
         box-shadow:inset 0px 0px 0px 0px;
         /*compensate for outer span's padding*/
         margin-left:-20px;  margin-top:-20px;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated you CSS by adding `margin: 10px` to the span tag. To get more space between the elements, please raise the margin.

You may find the updated jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RQ4F2/4/)